# How to Display a Facebook page which is passed viz a Server to a client's Browser

Tags: php, proxy

I want to display a Facebook's page which goes threw a web server and is displayed on the client's screen.

I created a PHP page and used the command file_get_content() to get a Facebook's page and Echoed it on the Screen. That works partially,  the login screen appears and it asks for ID and password and some time times Facebook says that the Browser is In compatible.

Whats the procedure to work around it ?

I used a Simple code like

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000564553314');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: if you told us what exactly you're hoping to accomplish you might get more responses. in fact, what i think you're trying to do sounds really shady to me.

Comment: Just experimenting :) Nothing shady about it.  Well Do you have any idea's regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

See example #4 on the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) man page. You'll have to set up a stream context, from which you can set a header that'll override PHP's internal UserAgent, and simulate a "real" browser.

Comment: Ill just try it, But the ID and Password that i will use for logging into Facebook will be submitted Directly to Facebook. So in this case the Connection Which passes Throw my Server would be Ended and a Direct Connection would be established B/w the Facebook server and the client